# Laravel email attach text file without actually creating the file

Tags: php, laravel-4

Using Laravel, is there a way to attach a file to an email without actually creating the file? Meaning, can I have the email include a text file attachment, but rather than actually saving the file somewhere and telling Laravel the path to the file, can I instead just pass Laravel the data I want to be included in the file?

I think the way to do this is something related to a memory stream but I'm not sure how to actually implement that.

Comment: I very much doubt it. Not a very common implementation, and not like creating files is very cumbersome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found an answer [here](http://laravel.io/forum/02-19-2014-need-to-mail-dynamically-created-pdf)

it's just

```
$message->attachData($StringValue, "Samplefilename.txt");
```

Comment: describe something here

Comment: This answer is correct, the attach data method will allow you to attach a file without creating it on the filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

I found this question as well, I needed to send csv files as an attachment without writing the file to the public directory where it could be accessed publicly by anyone. This method can be modified to send text files as well:

Send a txt file:

```
$filename =  'launch_codes.txt';
$file = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
fwrite($file,"nuclear_arsenal: swordfish");
rewind($file);
Mail::send('emails.launch_codes', [], function($message) use($file, $filename)
        {
            $message->to('please_not_trump@not-that-secure.gov')
                    ->subject('Confidential Data');
            $message->attachData(stream_get_contents($file), $filename);
        });

fclose($file);
```

Send a csv file:

```
        $filename =  'launch_codes.csv';
        $file = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
        $column_headers = ['Weapon', 'Launch Code'];
        fputcsv($file, $column_headers);
        fputcsv($file, [
           'nuclear_arsenal','swordfish'                        
        ]);

        rewind($file);

        Mail::send('emails.launch_codes', [], function($message) use($file, $filename)
        {
            $message->to('please_not_trump@not-that-secure.gov')
                    ->subject('Confidential Data');
            $message->attachData(stream_get_contents($file), $filename);
        });

        fclose($file);
```